# Change datatype of column in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I want to change the data type of one column in my `DataGridView` to be `Double`. This is because I have data to display in that `DataGridView` and I need to update/edit the value data from that `DataGridView`, that data type is `Double`.
 need to change one column (that have many rows) to double type. I want to change it because i want to compare the value with value of data on another column. in my database,PostgreSQL, I use double type of that column. When I run my program with above code, it shows Messagebox which said "Conversion from string 'Update hasillab set wbc ='10'I" to type 'Double' is not valid. It's not like my expectation

This code is not working:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dgv_hasillab.Rows.Count - 1
    dgv_hasillab.Columns(1).CellTemplate.ValueType = GetType(String)
Next
```

Comment: Firstly, it's NEVER acceptable to just say that something doesn't work.  It's ALWAYS necessary to explain exactly what does happen and exactly how that differs from your expectation.

Comment: Secondly, if you want to use `Double` values, how does it make sense to set the cell template value type to `String`?

Comment: Thirdly, what's the point of that loop?  There's only one column so why do you need to change it more than once?  You're not doing something for every cell in that column separately so how does it make sense to loop through the rows?  That's like setting the time on your phone for every shirt in your wardrobe.

Comment: Finally, I fixed the formatting of your code for you.  It's not hard to get the right number of spaces at the beginning of each line so please take the time to do so.  Answering questions is easier for us if everything is clearly formatted so please help us to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry if my explanantion is not clear.

I need to change one column (that have many rows) to double type.
I want to change it because i want to compare the value with value of data on another column.
in my database,PostgreSQL, I use double type of that column.

When I run my program with above code, it shows Messagebox which said "Conversion from string 'Update hasillab set wbc ='10'I" to type 'Double' is not valid

@jmcilhinney

Comment: @WindaSariElisabethSiburian : Could you please add that to question

Comment: The `CellTemplate` is the template from which new cells are created.  Any change you make to that has no effect on existing cells in that column.  You would need to either make a change to those cells directly or, better, configure the `CellTemplate` of the column before any cells are created.

Comment: That said, if the data in the grid is coming from a database then you shouldn't need to do anything to the grid.  You should be querying the data to populate a `DataTable` and binding that to the grid, so the `DataTable` controls data types.  If the data is numeric then the corresponding `DataColumn` should already have the appropriate data type set.  In short, you're almost certainly populating the grid incorrectly and that's what you need to fix.  As such, you need to show us how you're populating the grid so we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: i have added the more in the question @BRjava

Comment: I filled the datagridview not by bounding data from database. My data is from 2 tables and I manipulate it a little . I have medical check up data. One is from laboratory result table, the other is from table of standard value of laboratory. For example, I have result of laboratory check-up, like Hemoglobin. So, in result table, Hemoglobin(Hb) is name of column. BUt in my project, I want display all of my result of laboratory check-up with Hemoglobin as row. not column. I hope you all see the problem @jmcilhinney. so, the value of Hb is double. but when i want edit it in datagridview, it can't

Comment: *"I filled the datagridview not by bounding data from database"*. Then that is your first mistake.  Fix that and we can go from there.

Comment: I'm sorry . I mean, my data in datagridview is from database.@jmcilhinney

Answer (score 0):

May be its a late answer but I will share it anyway
after along search for a solution for this problem which I'm facing too.
The only solution i found is to make another copy of data-table with the wanted data types before connecting it to DataGridView then populate the modified data-table copy to DataGridView.

this code will help:

```
Dim datatableAllString As New DataTable

            For Each col As DataColumn In ORIGINALTABLE.Columns
                datatableAllString.Columns.Add(col.ColumnName, GetType(String))
            Next

            Dim newrow As DataRow

            For Each r As DataRow In ORIGINALTABLE.Rows
                newrow = datatableAllString.NewRow
                For i As Int32 = 0 To datatableAllString.Columns.Count - 1
                    newrow(i) = r.ItemArray(i).ToString()
                Next i
                datatableAllString.Rows.Add(newrow)
            Next r

           ORIGINALTABLE.Dispose()

            MY_DGV.DataSource = datatableAllString
```

you can change data type as per your requirements in the GetType() function for any column you choose while code looping.